# Subnet is in use and cannot be deleted issue when using pulumi destroy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pulumi

Due to some [issue with Pulumi cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941933/how-to-prevent-pulumi-cli-from-shuffling-configurations-in-stack-settings-file), I am using "Pulumi Azure Pipelines Task" in Azure DevOps pipeline as following:

- Pulumi up pipeline (`pulumi up -s dev`)
- Pulumi destroy pipeline (`pulumi destroy -s dev`)

Pulumi destroy pipeline was working fine until I created Application Gateway.
After adding Application Gateway, when Pulumi destroy pipeline is ruining, getting following error:

> error: Code="InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted" Message="Subnet ApplicationGatewaySubnet is in use by
> /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/xxx-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/xxx-appgw-agic-dev-japaneast/gatewayIPConfigurations/appgw_gateway_ipconfig
> and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet." Details=[]

I understand that it takes time to delete application gateway, but should not it be taken care by Pulumi by deleting resources sequentially
i.e. delete Subnet after Application Gateway deletion is completed

**How to destroy stack without causing "Xxx is in use and cannot be deleted" issue?**

The workaround is commenting out whole code and then running "Pulumi up pipeline". But that is not what I want, I want to use
"Pulumi destroy pipeline" to destroy stack properly without any issue.

## Update: 2021.11.18

For debugging purpose, I commented out all code except 3 simple resources:

- 1 Resource Group
- 1 Virtual Network
- 1 Subnet

**C# Code:**

```cs
//
// Added couple of extension methods to JsonElement
//

var mainRgArgs = config.RequireObject<JsonElement>(MainResourceGroupArgs);
var mainRgName = mainRgArgs.GetName();
var mainRgTags = mainRgArgs.GetTags();

var mainResourceGroup = new ResourceGroup(MainResourceGroup, new ResourceGroupArgs {
    ResourceGroupName = mainRgName,
    Tags = mainRgTags
});

var spokeVnetArgs = config.RequireObject<JsonElement>(SpokeVirtualNetworkArgs);
var spokeVnetName = spokeVnetArgs.GetName();
var spokeVnetAddressPrefixes = spokeVnetArgs.Get<List<string>>(AddressPrefixes);
var spokeVnetTags = spokeVnetArgs.GetTags();


var spokeVnetOutput = mainResourceGroup.Name.Apply(rgName => {

    return new VirtualNetwork(SpokeVirtualNetwork, new VirtualNetworkArgs {
        ResourceGroupName = rgName,
        VirtualNetworkName = spokeVnetName,
        AddressSpace = new AddressSpaceArgs {
            AddressPrefixes = spokeVnetAddressPrefixes
        },
        Tags = spokeVnetTags
    });

});


var spokeAksAppSubnetOutput = spokeVnetOutput.Apply(vnet => {

    return Output.Tuple(mainResourceGroup.Name, vnet.Name, vnet.Urn).Apply(tuple => {

        var (rgName, vnetName, vnetUniqueName) = tuple;

        var subnetName = AksApplicationSubnet;

        var subnets = spokeVnetArgs.GetSubnets() ?? new Dictionary<string, string>(); // GetSubnets() -> extension method

        if (!subnets.ContainsKey(subnetName)) {
            throw new PulumiArgumentException($"Value is not set for {nameof(subnetName)}");
        }

        var subnetCidr = subnets[subnetName];

        return new Subnet($"{vnetUniqueName}.{subnetName}", new AzureNative.Network.SubnetArgs {
            SubnetName = subnetName,
            AddressPrefix = subnetCidr,
            VirtualNetworkName = vnetName,
            ResourceGroupName = rgName,
        });
    });
});
```

From screenshot below, you can see that the delete sequence is wrong (Virtual Network > Resource Group > Subnet):
[image: Delete sequence of pulumi destroy is wrong]

> Info:
>
> 1. using "Pulumi Azure Pipelines Task" (version: 1.0.13) in Azure DevOps pipeline
> 2. Pulumi backend: Azure Blob Container & Azure KeyVault

Comment: Please share your code, it's hard to advise without it

Comment: @MikhailShilkov I did not share code because I thought `pulumi destroy` will simply destroy the entire stack without looking at code, is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: True, but the order of deletion is defined by dependencies as they were in the code at the time of the last deployment

Comment: @MikhailShilkov I added code and screenshot ("Update: 2021.11.18"). Can you please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating resources inside `Apply` callbacks which is highly discouraged. Not only will you not see them in the original preview, but also the dependency information is not preserved, as you discovered. A better approach would be something like this:

```cs
var mainResourceGroup = new ResourceGroup(MainResourceGroup, new ResourceGroupArgs {
    ResourceGroupName = mainRgName,
    Tags = mainRgTags
});

// ...

var spokeVnet = new VirtualNetwork(SpokeVirtualNetwork, new VirtualNetworkArgs {
    ResourceGroupName = mainResourceGroup.Name,
    VirtualNetworkName = spokeVnetName,
    AddressSpace = new AddressSpaceArgs {
        AddressPrefixes = spokeVnetAddressPrefixes
    },
    Tags = spokeVnetTags
});

// ...

var spokeAksAppSubnetOutput = new Subnet($"{vnetUniqueName}.{subnetName}", new AzureNative.Network.SubnetArgs {
    SubnetName = subnetName,
    AddressPrefix = subnetCidr,
    VirtualNetworkName = spokeVnet.Name,
    ResourceGroupName = mainResourceGroup.Name,
});
```

Note that you can assign outputs like `mainResourceGroup.Name` directly to inputs like `ResourceGroupName` - there is an implicit conversion operator for that.

You wouldn't be able to use outputs as the first argument of resource constructors (where you set the logical name) but hopefully you don't need to.

If you need an `Apply` somewhere, you can declare it separately and then use the result in resource assignment.

```cs
var myNewOutput = someResource.Prop1.Apply(v => ...);
new SomeOtherResource("name, new SomeOtherResourceArgs
{
    Prop2 = myNewOutput,
    // ...
});
```

This way the dependencies are correctly preserved for deletion.

If you want to provision multiple subnets, take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/903) to see how to do that sequentially if needed.

Comment: Following your answer, I tried to add 4 subnets and getting `error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="AnotherOperationInProgress" Message="Another operation on this or dependent resource is in progress. error: update failed`. Not sure if this has to do with Pulumi or Azure

Comment: I executed "`pulumi up` and then `pulumi destroy`" for 7 times & got error 2 times, so my conclusion is: it has to do with Azure, not Pulumi.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/903 - see some workarounds there in comments

Comment: Solved! Can you please address that also at bottom of your answer? (or I can suggest an edit)

Comment: I added a sentence at the bottom